# nodejs sequelize: I can't update the primary key field's value

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I can update every field's value except the id (primary key). It's for a website. I want to be able to update the id via the website.

```
module.exports = {
schema: function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define(
        'T_Event',
        {
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            user_id: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            created_at: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE
            },
            description: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            image: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            closed_at: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE
            }
        },
        {
            timestamps: true,
            paranoid: true,
            underscored: true,
            freezeTableName: true
        }
    )
}
```

I'm using sequelize 3.33.0 with node and a MySQL database.
All attributes have select,insert & update privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize restricts this kind of operation for security reasons. Usually updating a primary key through runtime with user provided information is a bad idea. It can lead to all sort of issues, especially if the changed object is being used by other users at the moment.

I follow the rule of thumb: if the column value can be changed, it is not a good candidate for a primary key. If there is no good candidate among all columns, create one with this sole purpose.

```
schema: function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define(
        'T_Event',
        {
            uid: {
                type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true
            },
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                unique: true
            },
            // ...
    )
}
```

That said, there are cases where this kind of solution isn't doable. In that case, you may use a workaround, making an update that changes the id:

```
T_Event.update(
    {
        id: new_value
    }, {
        where: {
            uid: current_value
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Super! I created a new column to work around this and got what i wanted. Many Thanks!